# Localhost giving an error "ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED "

Tags: php, localhost, wamp

I am trying to run a few php files using my localhost . I have wamp installed and its running fine. I created a folder in the "www" directory and the folder is visible when I run the localhost. Now I have a few .php files that I would like to run but I am unable to access them as I am receiving this error "ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED "

I researched on line and made changes to my index.php file. I changed the 
`$suppress_localhost = true; to $suppress_localhost = false;` but I am still receiving the same error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In which browser? Hope you are using Chrome, right?

Comment: What is the url you are trying to open in your browser?

Comment: i have tried both chrome and firefox
i simply type localhost in the address bar and i see the landing page then i  proceed to click on my project folder name and then i encounter this error.

Answer (score 1):

For all those who, like me, also end up here:
I had this error due to a mistake in thinking.

- I hosted my Laravel backend locally via xampp.
- but then tried to access it via an app on my smartphone.
  In the app I then specified blabla.test (http://localhost/htdocs-path/to/project/public/) as the servers url.
  But of course I needed the IP address of my PC.
  So http://192.168.2.173/htdocs-path/to/project/public/ was the correct local server url.

Answer (score 1):

I found this helpful for my issue. Browser cached the dns somehow. All I need to do just flush the dns caching.

For windows:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

See [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ipconfig).